# Macbook M1 connected to display randomly shuts down while sleeping

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, power-management, shutdown

A Macbook M1 connected to external display randomly shuts down while sleeping. The problem occurs regardless of the type of display connection (HDMI or USB-C). What can be the cause of this problem? I have AlDente free version running all the time, if this might help.

Comment: what are your sleep settings

Comment: `AiDente` Charge Limiter allows you to set your maximum charging percentage between 20 and 100 percent.

Comment: @Ruskes My charging limit is kept close to 60%. AlDente settings of the features “Stop charging when sleeping/App closed” are disabled; they are Pro features.

Comment: I do not know the AlDente, but would blame it for shutting down the computer